# Maximising correlation by finding the delay

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, signal-processing

I'm trying to find a value of delay which maximises the correlation between two vectors. I have enough data to truncate some values from each vector without compromising the accuracy of the results.

From other answers on here `plt.xcorr`, which seemed suitable for my application, however the results it gives are very weird. It gives a correlation value of above 0.9 for all values of delay between -5 and 5.

There are the first 10 values of my data frame `df`:

```
Date          Val1   Val2
2005-01-03    32.12  16.97
2005-01-04    31.88  16.96
2005-01-05    31.98  16.80
2005-01-06    32.60  17.12
2005-01-07    31.76  16.62
2005-01-10    31.96  16.83
2005-01-11    31.74  16.97
2005-01-12    32.02  17.42
2005-01-13    32.10  17.55
2005-01-14    32.19  17.98
```

When I apply `plt.xcorr(df.Val1,df.Val2)`
I get these correlations:

```
(array([-10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   1,   2,
          3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10]),
 array([ 0.97790633,  0.97825209,  0.97863114,  0.9789973 ,  0.97938754,
         0.97975968,  0.9801407 ,  0.98052259,  0.98091406,  0.9813025 ,
         0.98170846,  0.98122911,  0.98076348,  0.98030818,  0.97987819,
         0.97944349,  0.97901753,  0.97858155,  0.9781612 ,  0.97774505,
         0.97734392])
```

These can't be correct.
Am I doing anything wrong? 
Or, Does anyone have a better suggestion on how I can get the optimal delay to maximise the correlation value between my vectors?

Comment: Do you want to correlate the values, or the change in the values?

Comment: Good question! xcorr on the change in the values gives more plausible results. But from previous examples it's usually applied to the time series itself.

Comment: What makes you so sure that those correlation coefficients aren't correct? You've only shown us 10 points from each series. If you have 1000s of points in each series, and they show similar trends over longer timescales, then it's entirely possible to see correlation coefficients that high. Have you tried plotting them?